# Is there a reason Windows Modules Installer Worker uses only one cpu core?

Tags: windows-10, cpu, performance, windows-update, cpu-usage

It is well known that Windows Modules Installer Worker (windows update) does not really care about resource efficiency, and just takes whatever cpu %, ram and disk usage it wants. I suppose I already got used to that.

Using *Intel Core I7-10510U cpu* (and 16GB ram), it takes 25%-26% on average:

[image: resources usage]

But I was surprised to discover that **it only uses one cpu core** and exhausts it to the max, causing a heat spike that affect other cores, and overall prevents an efficient cpu usage:

[image: cpu usage]

Why is it doing so? Is there a way to force it use other cores or just take less cpu?

**My main concern is all the heat** it generates, and the long time it takes while maxing out a whole cpu core!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not unusual for a single-threaded task to completely eat up one core. It's an intelligent decision. It saves having to supervise & intelligently throttle its activity, stops it running rampant & eating your whole CPU & it saves the scheduler from having to find it some room to get its elbows out.

The heat discrepancy between cores used this way should be insignificant. I've run single-core apps for years with no heat issues - & certainly no 'handing it over & making other cores look hot'. If it's actually doing that, perhaps investigate cooling & what other processes may be running.

Your posted image would seem to show no real issues - you have 2 cores at 84, the rest in the low 60s. If that's a 4-core, 8 with HT, then one physical core will display temps for both virtual cores, as they're physically one.

I just checked - it is a 4-core - https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/196449/intel-core-i7-10510u-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-90-ghz.html

Comment: Good answer. I just miss one detail. It is far easier to make a single treated program than a multi-treated program. So unless you really want and need a multi-treated program, developers often don't even go with the trouble. In some cases, spreading a load between multiple treats is really difficult. In the case of windows installer, if it just installs one update but it is a big update, it is very difficult to create multiple programs each consuming a core to effectively install the windows update. This would also mean that the installation of updates must be regulated far more than it does.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, and @LPChip for your additional comment. Today's update did take longer than usual. I didn't want to stop it since it was at 60% when I found out, yet I really needed to start working and use my VMs.. Is there a way to limit the cpu usage / priority of that process? It just amazes me that after all those years windows 10 update service is still such an issue in many aspects.

Comment: The thing is... it will also do that on an idle 76-core server. not bouncing between cores is good (but a scheduler decision unless the cpu mask of the .exe was modified), but letting a maintenance task take an hour where it could be, say, 20 minutes is something where having a choice would be good. I'll side with the team that says they went the easy way.